# matplotlib - autosize of text according to shape size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm adding a text inside a shape by:
`ax.text(x,y,'text', ha='center', va='center',bbox=dict(boxstyle='circle', fc="w", ec="k"),fontsize=10)` (ax is AxesSubplot)

The problem is that I couldn't make the circle size constant while changing the string length. I want the text size adjust to the circle size and not the other way around.
The circle is even completely gone if the string is an empty one.

The only bypass to the problem I had found is dynamically to set the fontsize param according to the len of the string, but that's too ugly and not still the circle size is not completely constant.

**EDIT (adding a MVCE):**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

ax.text(0.5,0.5,'long_text', ha='center', va='center',bbox=dict(boxstyle='circle', fc="w", ec="k"),fontsize=10)
ax.text(0.3,0.7,'short', ha='center', va='center',bbox=dict(boxstyle='circle', fc="w", ec="k"),fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Trying to make both circles the same size although the string len is different. Currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gabriel, Added, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very dirty and hard-core solution which requires quite deep knowledge of matplotlib.  It is not perfect but might give you some ideas how to start.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np
plt.close('all')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 8))

t1 = ax.text(0.5,0.5,'long_text', ha='center', va='center',fontsize=10)
t2 = ax.text(0.3,0.7,'short', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10)
t3 = ax.text(0.1,0.7,'super-long-text-that-is-long', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10)

fig.show()

def text_with_circle(text_obj, axis, color, border=1.5):
    # Get the box containing the text
    box1 = text_obj.get_window_extent()
    # It turned out that what you get from the box is 
    # in screen pixels, so we need to transform them 
    # to "data"-coordinates.  This is done with the 
    # transformer-function below
    transformer = axis.transData.inverted().transform
    # Now transform the corner coordinates of the box
    # to data-coordinates
    [x0, y0] = transformer([box1.x0, box1.y0])
    [x1, y1] = transformer([box1.x1, box1.y1])
    # Find the x and y center coordinate
    x_center = (x0+x1)/2.
    y_center = (y0+y1)/2.
    # Find the radius, add some extra to make a nice border around it
    r = np.max([(x1-x0)/2., (y1-y0)/2.])*border
    # Plot the a circle at the center of the text, with radius r.
    circle = Circle((x_center, y_center), r, color=color)
    # Add the circle to the axis.
    # Redraw the canvas.
    return circle 

circle1 = text_with_circle(t1, ax, 'g')
ax.add_artist(circle1)

circle2 = text_with_circle(t2, ax, 'r', 5)
ax.add_artist(circle2)

circle3 = text_with_circle(t3, ax, 'y', 1.1)
ax.add_artist(circle3)

fig.canvas.draw()
```

At the moment you have to run this in ipython, because the figure has to be drawn BEFORE you `get_window_extent()`.  Therefore the `fig.show()` has to be called AFTER the text is added, but BEFORE the circle can be drawn!  Then we can get the coordinates of the text, figures out where the middle is and add a circle around the text with a certain radius.  When this is done we redraw the canvas to update with the new circle.  Ofcourse you can customize the circle a lot more (edge color, face color, line width, etc), look into [the Circle class](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=circle#matplotlib.patches.Circle).

Example of output plot:
[image]

Comment: The 'right' way to do this is to compute the size _at_ draw time which is what mpl does internally.

Comment: @tcaswell I actually realised that I did not answer the OP's question.  It said "Trying to make both circles the same size although the string len is different."  I will make a new solution when I get home today.

Comment: ha, I read your answer and also did not read the question carefully.